# Split string by two conditions

Tags: java, string, scala, split

I have to split this string from

```
val str="s: saturday, sunday, solar, selfie"
```

into an Array

```
s,saturday,sunday,solar,selfie
```

in scala 2.10

Comment: `str.replaceAll(":" , "").split(',');`?

Comment: or `split("[:,] ")`

Comment: If @Sarz had not deleted his answer converting the first string into the second, I would have upvoted it for its unassuming reading of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in Java you would write

```
String text = "s: saturday, sunday, solar, selfie";
String[] words = text.split("[:,] ");
```

This will split by an `:` or `,` followed by a space.  If the space is optional you could use `"[:,] ?"`

Comment: scala is similar to java just we have to put `val` in place of `String[]` ;)

Answer (score 3):

From the perspective of the string to be split:

```
val text = "s: saturday, sunday, solar, selfie"
val words = text.split("[:,] ")
```

Scala uses the same method as in `java.lang.String`.

---

As an alternative, from the perspective of the regex:

```
val str = "s: saturday, sunday, solar, selfie"
val regex = "[:,] ".r
val words = regex.split(str)
```

Possibly interesting if the regex is complex, and you want to reuse it multiple times.
The `.r` is a method in `StringLike` which returns a `Regex`.

Comment: +1 for "the perspective of the string to be split". So much postmodern lit is from the perspective of the oppressed.

Comment: @som-snytt Well, I'm not a native English speaker, so I wasn't even aware of the kind of lyrics I have written down. But well, yes, freedom for the tokens :-)

Answer (score 1):

`str=str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""); String[] array=str.split("\\s");`
//use this to first remove all the special characters and then splitting it into string array

Comment: there should be double \\s in split

Comment: `.split("\\W+")`